# apt-get stuck in strongswan-starter_5.5.1 after upgrade my ubuntu to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install certbot after I upgrade my ubuntu. However, I'm stuck at the error

> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The
>   following packages have unmet dependencies:  strongswan-starter :
>   Depends: libstrongswan (= 5.5.1-1ubuntu3.2) but 5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2 is
>   installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with
>   no packages (or specify a solution).

I have tried to run

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

but what I get is

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> /var/cache/apt/archives/strongswan-starter_5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The truth is that I don't want strongswan and any related package in my system. But when I try to unstall it I get the same error as I want to upgrade it.

Any hints?

thanks

---

my `sources.list` (some are hided)

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
```

more information is found from running dpkg --list

```
ii  strongswan                    5.5.1-1ubuntu3.2    all                 IPsec VPN solution metapackage
ii  strongswan-charon             5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2    amd64               strongSwan Internet Key Exchange daemon
ii  strongswan-libcharon          5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2    amd64               strongSwan charon library
ii  strongswan-starter            5.5.1-1ubuntu3.2    amd64               strongSwan daemon starter and configuration file parser
```

after run `sudo apt remove libstrongswan` i have the following error :-(

```
sudo apt remove libstrongswan
Reading package lists... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcharon-standard-plugins : Depends: libstrongswan (= 5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libstrongswan-standard-plugins : Depends: libstrongswan (= 5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 strongswan-libcharon : Depends: libstrongswan (= 5.5.1-4ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 strongswan-starter : Depends: libstrongswan (= 5.5.1-1ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

I have tried to run dpkg -P strongswan-* in command, but strongswan-libcharon and  strongswan-starter have me error anyway.

here is log

```
dpkg -P strongswan-starter
(Reading database ... 148684 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing strongswan-starter (5.5.1-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Failed to stop strongswan.service: Unit strongswan.service not loaded.
Failed to stop strongswan.service: Unit strongswan.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package strongswan-starter (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read strongswan.service
Failed to get unit file state for strongswan.service: No such file or directory
strongswan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read strongswan.service
Failed to get unit file state for strongswan.service: No such file or directory
strongswan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 strongswan-starter
```

Comment: 5.5.1-1 is 17.04, 5.5.1-4 is 17.10. Check your sources - the most common reason for failure of this sort is a failed release-upgrade, and you are still using 17.04 sources.

Comment: I have checked the /etc/apt/source.list. I think it is fine

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
....

Comment: You installed *something* that depends upon the 17.04 version of strongswan. Perhaps a PPA or some other non-Ubuntu software?